# RegionCode in YouTube API v3

Tags: youtube-data-api

I can't seem to find any information on the implications of using/not using regionCode in the YouTube v3 API, for example the [search/list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) resource.

In the specific, if the regionCode is not specified in the call to the API, will all the videos matching the criteria be returned? 
If a video is allowed only in certain regions, not specifying the regionCode in the search request, will the API return it? Or only the unrestricted videos will be returned?

Where can I find some clarification on the topic?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify the Region Code then the API automatically determines the region based on your location. So, for example, if I queried the API on my laptop in New Zealand, then the region code would be NZ.

The API outputs the region code. In JSON it is under the tag regionCode.

Answer (score -1):

Generally Region Code is not required. You will get a good matching results output without it.
The regionCode parameter instructs the API to return search results for the specified country. The parameter value is an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code. (string)